# How do you get SQL Server 2008 Server Agent login credentials?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I would like to learn how to use SQL Server. My school offers the software as part of its enrollment package so I decided to download it and try installing it. Unfortunately, I get stuck at the following installation screen:

[image: Http://www.pinaldave.com/blogfolder/2008/200814.jpg]

No matter what name and password I enter for any of the fields, it comes back telling me that these are invalid. Where and how do I get valid login credentials? Am I supposed to register somewhere somehow?

Any help appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: **NOT** programming-related in any way, shape for form --> belongs on [Serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) where sysadmins and DBAs hang out

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a local install you can leave it at the default one's OR create a local user account on your box and give it those to use.

If you use the default one's you don't supply them passwords.

Answer (score 2):

The various machine accounts like `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` and `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` do not require you to enter a password, and you shouldn't try to. They already have a preconfigured password which you don't have access to. This is why the password field is disabled in your image.

Leave those accounts set the way they are, and continue with your install. If it refuses to allow you continue, then you have either changed something, or there is something else wrong (not the passwords).

Comment: Sorry if I am being brain-dead, but it will not let me continue no matter what I do.. It keeps saying that I need to provide a valid account and password for the SQL Server Agent Service.. I have no idea why its asking me where others had no issues, and I don't know where I could find this information.

Comment: I wonder if the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user has been disabled on your machine (strange, but maybe)? Or if you have managed to lock the account by messing with the password? Have you tried creating a local user account with sufficient privileges and run them as that? (the `SYSTEM` account is highly privileged, the `NETWORK SERVICE` one is quite low). In any case, try checking the installation log and see if it offers you more specific details.

Comment: Look at install log to find clues to what causes this. These logs are usually very detailed.